# Angular populate Bootstrap modal form from controller data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to populate a modal form with data passed in from my controller.  The data being displayed is always `NULL`, even though I have populated the data in the controller.

I have been trying to work this out and have tried a few different ways to do it but none work.

The examples I have seen use $scope, but I don't want to use $scope and instead use controller as

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($uibModal, $log) {

      var vm = this;

        vm.vehicle = [{
            vehicleRegistration: null,
            createUser: null
        }];

        vm.open = function (size) {
            vm.vehicle[0]["vehicleRegistration"] = 'ABCDEFG';
            vm.vehicle[0]["createUser"] = 'BOBF';

            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                    items: function () {
                        return vm.vehicle;
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    });
})();


(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance, items) {
        var vm = this;
        // I want to get the vehicle data pass to populate the form myModalContent.html
        vm.vehicle = items;
    });
})();
```

Any ideas?

Here is http://plnkr.co/edit/grHKGEJeKqoR8VHOW8I6?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use another name than vm for the modal. I've set it to vm2, also when defining the modal, you have to set the alias for the controller using the word *as* like this:

```
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl as vm2',
  size: 'lg',
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return vm.vehicle;
    }
  }
});
```

Check the link: http://plnkr.co/edit/JmCL6NjAmd2b1UPR8649